# os.networkInterfaces is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular

```
    var os = require('os');
var ifaces = os.networkInterfaces();
var lib = {};

lib.networkInterfaces = function () {
    return os.networkInterfaces();
};
```

Above code has to return networkInterfaces but it through error "os.networkInterfaces is not a function", above code is inside a node module that i have installed in my angular project

```
{
```

"name": "@braj1996/tiny",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "os":"0.1.1"
  }
}

And this is the package.json file detail inside the node module

```
ngOnInit() {
console.log(TinyJS.networkInterfaces());
```

}

And this is code that i used in my component.ts file to get the output

NOTE:- The above node module is my custom node module i build it and packaged it.But i don't get it what is wrong in my packaging.

Comment: Angular apps run in the browser. Not in NodeJS. They don't have access to the network interfaces of the OS.

Comment: so how can i achieve it ?I just want to get the mac address of the system

Comment: JavaScript in browser runs in a secure sandbox, meaning that it doesn't have access to underlying machine. Only to browser itself. Imagine what could be done by hackers, if javascript had permissions to read or even write from/to secure places of your disk.

Comment: But there are NPM that do this for us, so how they achieve it like (https://www.npmjs.com/package/getmac)